read different schema and insert into target in azure
I am reading data from parquet files and inserting into my target table.
I am into the situation that as like below
yesterday received a file with below columns as
Col1 Col2 Col3
AAA  123  456

and loaded into my target
INSERT into target
SLEECT
Col1
Col2
Col3 
From file path

and defined a schema(using structfileds) and loaded the into my target table.
Now the problem is Today I received a file lesser columns
Col1  Col2
 BBB    890


INSERT into target
    SLEECT
    Col1
    Col2
    Col3 
    From file path

Now while inserting this data into my target table it is throwing an error as the fields does not exist.
File columns may vary on day to day  (it means that we will get less columns also)
Can anyone suggest me how to overcome this issue.
Regards,
Khatija

what is your target table location?

Hi Bhavani, Thanks for your response. location is delta lake and it will be inserted into my fact table.


the field does not exist

Your second file is having two columns and target table is having three columns, that may be the reason to get above error while inserting values from second file into target table. To resolve above error, you can replace Null value in place of Col3 as below:
INSERT into target
SELECT
Col1,
Col2 ,
Null
FROM <filePath>

Then you will be able to the second file values into the target table as shown below:


It always goes as NULL into my target if I receive a data which is not correct

Didn't get you,can you provide sample example?

Let me explain, I have an employee file which has 3 columns as name,employeeid,sal. Today i received a source file which data for all 3 columns. In this case there is no issue when insert into your target table.
Suppose some other day if I get a file which has data only for columns name,employeeid and I don't have any headers for Sal column in the file. Now this time it will check for Sal column and it fails since it is not available in the file

According to the question your requirement is satisfied, you are facing new issue, please raise new question with your new requirement.
